# mixup for gray image input and color image output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-processing, deep-learning

Mixup is a technique to smoothen the training of a neural network by applying convex combination to training inputs:

https://keras.io/examples/vision/mixup/

In the example, the input is gray image and the output is a label. For example, if we create a new image = 0.3 * a shoe + 0.7 * a sweater then the label for that new image would be label = 0.3 * shoe + 0.7 * sweater. Lambda = 0.3.

However, I am thinking of applying this technique to a dataset that input gray image and output color image. I would like to ask whether the application of lambda is still technically the same for the gray image (1 channel) and the color image (3 channels):

```
def mix_up(ds_one, ds_two, alpha=0.2):
    # Unpack two datasets
    images_one, outputs_one = ds_one
    images_two, outputs_two = ds_two
    batch_size = tf.shape(images_one)[0]

    # Sample lambda and reshape it to do the mixup
    lambda = sample_beta_distribution(batch_size, alpha, alpha)
    x_l = tf.reshape(lambda, (batch_size, 1, 1, 1))
    y_l = tf.reshape(lambda, (batch_size, 1, 1, 1))

    # Perform mixup on both images and labels by combining a pair of images/labels
    # (one from each dataset) into one image/label
    images = images_one * x_l + images_two * (1 - x_l)
    outputs = outputs_one * y_l + outputs_two * (1 - y_l)
    return (images, outputs)
```

Comment: I'd say yes. the blended output still correlates with the blended input. the blending of input and output respectively would be reasonable to perform with the same lambda, not any function of lambda. -- IDK how well that mixup technique applies to high dimensional output (images), versus simple classification. -- you might wanna ask this on http://stats.stackexchange.com/ because it's fundamentally a conceptual question. implementation details don't appear to be the issue.

Comment: By saying color ouput, you mean channel==3, right? not like actual RGB color? If so, why not converting 1 channel input to 3 channel?

Comment: I know it is the same lambda, but notice that in the example, they need to reshape lambda to fit the image input (256x256x1) and label output (1). what I am asking is how to reshape the lambda for a color image output (256x256x3)

Comment: oh that? well, depends on whether you'd want different channels to be mixed differently, or all the same. if you need them mixed the same, you leave the `sample_beta_distribution()` as is, and reshape with the extra channel dimension being 1. -- actually, since that's already in NHWC/NCHW shape, you don't need to change anything. ***did you try the code on color outputs before asking?***

Comment: what is NHWC/NCHW?

Comment: I want to mix the two color outputs into a convex combination one, ie I want to be technically correct about the mixing

Answer (score 0):

The given code already assumes **N**CHW/**N**HWC shape for inputs and outputs.

The given code should work as is.